# Core Data: One entity, 15 attributes, 4 Scenes. How to save to the same object?

Tags: ios, core-data, pointers, attributes, save

I have one Entity (called Meetings) that has 20 attributes.  In storyboard I have 4 scenes.  Obviously each scene has it's own controller file.  Each scene provides 5 UITextField's for user input.  I'd like to save when the user hits Next on each scene.  Saving would be to the same entity object that was created in Scene1.  I'm able to save in scene 1 just fine.  But when I get to scene 2, how do I access the same object that I saved to in Scene 1?

Below is the code for Scene 1 to create the object:

```
Meetings *meetings = (Meetings *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meetings" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Problem:  How do I access the same pointer *meetings that was created in Scene 1 from Scene2, 3, and 4?  When I type the same code above in Scene 2, 3, and 4, it gives me a new Object.  I don't want create a new object past Scene1.  I'd like access to the same object from Scene1 so I can continue to save in remaining attributes.

Or is there better approach to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to insert new meetings object at every scene.

1. Just pass meetings reference from one scene to second and etc.
2. Or pass meetings objectID

   ```
   @implementation FirstScene
   ...

   - (void)nextScene {
       Meetings *meetings = (Meetings *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meetings" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
       NSManagedObjectID* objectID = [meetings objectID];
       [secondScene setObjectID:objectID];
   }
   ...
   @end

   @implementation SecondScene
   ...
   - (void)setObjectID:(NSManagedObjectID*)objectId {
       NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self context];
       Meetings *theSameMeetings = (Meetings *)[context objectWithID:objectID];
   }

   ...
   @end
   ```

Comment: Thank you.  I had a feeling I'd have to use ObjectIDs. I have a class and tied up for the rest of the day.  I will give this a shot tomorrow AM and get back to you.

Comment: It not bad if you just use reference to 'meetings' object. Usually objectID uses to pass managed object between threads.

Comment: So I'm doing it by objectID.  At first I got an error in FirstScene with [secondScene setObjectID:objectID]; "No known class method for selector 'setObjectID'.

Comment: So I changed the the declaration in SecondScene.h and .m file from (-) to (+). So the declaration reads: 
+(void)setObjectID:(NSManagedObjectID*)objectID;  That made the error in FirstScene go away; however, now I have an error in SceneTwo with line: NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];  No known class method for selector 'managedObjectContext'.  I changed context to managedObjectContext b/c in SecondScene in viewDidLoad, I have the following line: self.managedObjectContext = [(STAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  delegate] managedObjectContext];

Comment: I've gave you just simple example, hoping that you will be able to pick up from there. Sorry if  I mislead you.

Comment: Hey, no need to apologize. I appreciate you trying to help. I think you steered my in right direction. I just need to figure out the syntax in the Second Scene on how to capture self.managedObjectContext into *context.